# copy specific row from multiple table into another table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I want to copy a specific row from tables temperature, rules and schedule to stats table.

In temperature table, I want the latest temperature which is 18.6

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM currenttemp ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC limit 10 ;
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| timestamp           | sensor          | currenttemp | humidity | pressure |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 2017-03-25 15:28:03 | sensor-1stFloor |        18.6 |    49.85 |  1021.26 |
| 2017-03-25 15:27:03 | sensor-1stFloor |        18.7 |    49.81 |  1021.26 |
| 2017-03-25 15:26:03 | sensor-1stFloor |        18.8 |    49.82 |  1021.26 |
| 2017-03-25 15:25:03 | sensor-1stFloor |        18.9 |    49.85 |  1021.22 |
| 2017-03-25 15:24:03 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.99 |    49.83 |  1021.21 |
| 2017-03-25 15:23:03 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.61 |    49.85 |  1021.18 |
| 2017-03-25 15:22:02 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.62 |     49.8 |   1021.3 |
| 2017-03-25 15:21:02 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.63 |    49.82 |  1021.39 |
| 2017-03-25 15:20:03 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.61 |    49.82 |  1021.28 |
| 2017-03-25 15:19:03 | sensor-1stFloor |       18.62 |    49.82 |  1021.37 |
+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

In rules table, I want the targettemp for schedule 4 which is 40

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM rules limit 10 ;
+----+----------+--------+------------+
| id | schedule | sensor | targettemp |
+----+----------+--------+------------+
|  1 |        4 | 1      |         40 |
|  2 |        5 | 1      |          5 |
+----+----------+--------+------------+
```

In schedule table, I want the endtime for id 4 which is 10:00:00

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM schedules limit 10 ;
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+--------+
| id | friendlyname | dayofweek | pretimestart | timestart | endtime  | enabled | targettemp | sensor |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+--------+
|  4 | test         | 1111110   | 00:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 10:00:00 |       1 |         30 | 1      |
|  5 | sun          | 0000001   | 00:00:00     | 00:00:00  | 20:00:00 |       0 |          0 |        |
+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+---------+------------+--------+
```

I then want to insert these data to the stats table

currenttemp which is 18.6
targettemp for schedule 4 which is 40
endtime for id 4 which is 10:00:00

the timestamp is done automatically
state will be between ON and OFF

please look at the 1st row in stats table as example from the data copied from the above tables.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stats limit 10 ;
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
| timestamp           | currenttemp | targettemp | endtime  | state |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-03-25 15:41:46 |        18.6 |         40 | 10:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 16:53:05 |       16.83 |          5 | 00:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 16:54:14 |       16.83 |         40 | 00:00:00 | ON    |
| 2017-03-19 20:04:07 |       16.58 |         40 | 00:00:00 | ON    |
| 2017-03-19 20:04:15 |       16.58 |          5 | 00:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 20:06:29 |       16.58 |          5 | 00:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 20:34:28 |       16.54 |          5 | 00:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 20:34:56 |       16.54 |          5 | 00:00:00 | OFF   |
| 2017-03-19 20:35:26 |       16.54 |         40 | 00:00:00 | ON    |
| 2017-03-19 20:38:05 |       16.54 |         40 | 00:00:00 | ON    |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

I will have 2 queries. One with the state OFF and one with the state ON.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the layout of the data.  It is unclear.

Comment: Could you turn the addresses of the images from code to hyperlinks?

Comment: Add the layout and sample data as *text* in the question.

Comment: Hi Gordon and toonice, thanks for coming back to me. i have reworded the question and hope it's clearer to you. many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work

```
INSERT INTO stats (currenttemp,targettemp,endtime,state)
SELECT 
 temperature,r.targettemp,s.timeend,'OFF'
FROM 
 schedules s
 INNER JOIN rules r 
    ON s.id = r.schedule
 INNER JOIN temperature
 WHERE timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM temperature)
 AND s.id = 4
```

i can see now in my stats table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stats limit 10 ;
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
| timestamp           | currenttemp | targettemp | endtime  | state |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-04-06 17:58:05 |       19.53 |         40 | 10:00:00 | OFF   |
+---------------------+-------------+------------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because the relationship between `temperature` and the other tables is unclear.  Let me assume that there is a join key to `schedules`.  If so, the query you want would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO stats (currenttemp, targettemp, endtime)
    SELECT t.temperature, r.targettemp, s.timeend
    FROM schedules s INNER JOIN
         rules r
         ON s.id = r.schedule INNER JOIN
         temperature t
         ON t.schedule = s.id
    WHERE s.id = 4 AND
          t.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp)
                         FROM temperature t2
                         WHERE t2.schedule = t.schedule
                        );
```

Comment: there is no relation between temperature and the other table. i just want to pull out from temperature the latest entry based on its timestamp. thanks